# How to highlight (or select) a file (or folder) programmatically in Linux environment (using java)

Tags: java, linux, eclipse, eclipse-rcp, desktop

I'm trying to launch the file browser with the specified path using Desktop API, It only launches the dialog with NO selection (or Highlighting ) made on the specified file (or Folder). In Windows, I'm able to do it using Explorer.exe like :

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("explorer.exe /select," + path);
```

I need the same behaviour in Linux also.

Any ways to achieve this ?

Suggestions are welcomed !!

Comment: There are various versions of Linux, which have different solutions for the file explorer (e.g. Nautilus, Dolphin). So there is no single solution to rule them all.

Comment: @hotzst : Thanks for your answer. But I wonder why Desktop API doesn't have the support of highlighting the files (or folders) in addition to opening the browser dialog :(

Answer (score 0):

Could you try something like this.

```
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec("nautilus"+path);
```